# AspectJ in Spring Boot causes ClassNotFoundException during startup

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, aspectj

I have created this simple Spring Boot application to illustrate the issue I have found, that makes my application to fail with a ClassNotFoundException during startup.

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>AspectJ test for spring boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DemoConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"my.code"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class DemoConfiguration {

}
```

**MyAnnotation.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

**MyAnnotationAspect.java**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAnnotationAspect {   
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAnnotationAspect.class);
    @Around("@annotation(MyAnnotation)")
    public Object myAnnotation (ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        logger.debug("Before");
        Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.debug("After");
        return proceed;
    }
}
```

As you can infer, I am attempting to create a custom annotation using AspectJ and spring aop. Unfortunately, in this setup I get an exception while spring boot starts up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I am checking maven dependencies on the classpath - I use Eclipse IDE -, and I see aspectjweaver.jar there. And it has the right class.

Any hints are welcome.

EDIT: I have tried installing the AspectJ compiler in Eclipse, as per another question from a couple of years ago that was similar. No changes.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I found the root cause for this issue: maven downloaded a corrupted version of the relevant aspectjweaver jar. When I physically deleted it (mvn -U compile did not work) from my hard drive and forced it to reload, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instrument spring-boot-plugin with java-agent. Configure it as following.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <jvmArguments>
            -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar
        </jvmArguments>
        <attach>false</attach>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

PS. make sure you have that dependency in your local repo.

Hopefully, it should solve your problems.